# Using a model without migration ? ( just SELECT in database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I already have a database with the right structure.

I would like to create a rails app just to read into this database, I don't want to insert neither update etc...

Actually, I would like to use rails but handle myself the creation of the database and tables.

Is it possible ?

I've commented every lines into "create" def into the migration file, it works but is there another way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails g model ModelName --skip-migration
```

Comment: Oh ok, I use Rubymine, then I never saw this option. Thank you ! (I'll try tomorrow)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this Gem.

```
        gem 'rmre', '~> 0.0.8'
```

It allows you to create models from an existing schema.

See documentation here: https://github.com/bosko/rmre